# i wonder!! why there is no Object interface in java?

Tags: java, object

if there is one, then any one could implement its own object depending on what is their requirement.(ie how they want to implement their own locking mechanism, their own memory realization etc.). 
but there is no object interface provided by java creator. Any specific reason?

Comment: Object is a native Class. It provides base methods that every Class needs. If you want to change them, you can just @Override them. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's not how things work. Especially not with interfaces. It's also not the point of Java to create your own memory handling or locking mechanisms. It's to create useful software. If you want to write memory handling code, choose a different language.

Answer (score 1):

An interface in Java only has the method type, name and some parameters and the actual implementation is done in a class that implements it. So you never create object for an interface. You can have a local variable for that interface type and the value assigned to that variable would refer to an instance of some concrete implementation of the interface.

All in all, the actual object will always be an instance of some concrete implementation.

Comment: Moreover, if one wants a custom implementation, nothing stops them from extending the class, right?

Comment: Absolutely. A class is your playground.